# Can the question asker (<10K rep) see deleted answers to their own questions?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I realise that users with less than 10K rep can't usually see deleted answers, but I'm wondering if there is an exception when a user asks a question? Can they see deleted answers (from other users) to their own questions?

Comment: The FAQ (section: "[Can I still see my own post even after it's deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/282094)" up to the section: "What else should I know about deleted posts?") answers this question. --- If you think a sentence should be added or an existing one made more clear you are allowed (encouraged) to edit the answer.

Comment: This isn't what you asked about but <10k users can see deleted _questions_ to which they had posted an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on *why* the answer was deleted.

- If the answer was deleted not by itself, but because the *question* was deleted, the author of the question can see it.
- If the answer was deleted for another reason, they can't.

Comment: Here you assume the asker deleted their question? It is a bit confusing. What can an <10k asker see of deleted answers?

Comment: @rene mod deletion would have the same effect right?

Comment: I tested it with mod deletion, but I assume it doesn't make a difference.